# Solving equations with trigon functions `NSolve`, `FindRoot`

Tags: equation-solving

I have a simple equation:

```
(Sin[ϕ] Cos[xx])/Sin[xx] == 0.75
```

If I try:

```
NSolve[(Sin[ϕ] Cos[xx])/Sin[xx] == 0.75, xx, Reals]
```

I get

```
NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
{{xx -> ConditionalExpression[1. (-2.57352 + 6.28319 C[1]), 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]}, {xx -> 
   ConditionalExpression[1. (0.568075 + 6.28319 C[1]), 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
```

For this one in particular, I have to use `FindRoot`. Why?

The problem I get is with this one:

```
aaLow = 53.*Degree;
ϕ = 28.6*Degree;
faa[δ_, ha_] := Module[{sigCot, sigSin, aa, res},
   If[Sin[ha] == 0,
    (* avoid singularities *)
    res = 2 π - ha;,
    aa = (Tan[δ] Cos[ϕ] - Sin[ϕ] Cos[ha])/Sin[ha];
    (* determine the necessary signs to get quadrant *)
    sigCot = Sign[aa];
    sigSin = -Sign[Sin[ha]];
    aa = Abs@ArcCot[aa];
    (* get quadrant *)
    Switch[
     {sigSin, sigCot},
     {1, 1}, res = aa,
     {1, -1}, res = π - aa,
     {-1, 1}, res = π + aa,
     {-1, -1}, res = 2 π - aa
     ];
    ];
   res
   ];
```

When I try:

```
FindRoot[faa[0.5, z]== aaLow, {z, 0.5}]
```

I get

```
FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {-0.925025+res$8084} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {z} = {0.5`}">>
```

Not even `FindRoot[faa[0, z], {z, 0.5}]== aaLow` which should reduce to the first example (except the right hand side).

What am I doing wrong when trying to get the solution?

Some more notes, `δ∈[-π/2,π/2]`,`ha∈[-π/2,π/2]`.

### Update

It seems there is something wrong with the definition of the `faa` function.

```
FindRoot[faa[0, x] == aaLow, {x, 0.5}]
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-0.925025+res$72908} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {0.5}. >>
```

but

```
FindRoot[ArcCot[(Tan[0] Cos[ϕ] - Sin[ϕ] Cos[x])/Sin[x]] == 
  aaLow, {x, 0.5}]
{x -> -0.565933}
```

Comment: I would have said that `NSolve` succeeded, so no need for `FindRoot`.  What's the problem with its solution?  (I also wonder what it has to do with the rest of the question.  *Prima facie* it looks like it is a separate question.)

Comment: May be it is not your aim, but this `Solve[(Sin[\[Phi]] Cos[xx])/Sin[xx] == 3/4, xx, Reals]` gives an exact solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2 There are several problems, the obvious is the warning, the second one is what is C[1] and finally, how do I access the results. The error suggests that I am doing something wrong and potentially Mathematica illegal. The second example is a more general one which reduces to the first one for `\[delta]=0`. Specifically, there must be something wrong with my definition of the faa function, see  the updated question.

Comment: `C[1]` represents any integer.  Set it equal to something inside `Block[{C},..]` or replace it with `C[1] -> 2` or another integer instead of `2`.  Example: `Join @@ Block[{C}, Table[{{xx -> ConditionalExpression[1. (-2.57352 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {xx -> ConditionalExpression[1. (0.568075 + 6.28319 C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}, {C[1], -3, 3}]]`